# Вечное ожидания запроса

Tags: c#, unity3d, unity3d-android

Я отправляю запрос на некий сервер, и ожидаю ответа, но тут проблема, если отослать запрос и выключить интернет (или отправить запрос с выключенным интернетом) то это yield return не даст продолжить выполняться корутине никогда, как это можно поправить?

```
 UnityWebRequest www = new UnityWebRequest("https://***.php")
     {
         downloadHandler = new DownloadHandlerBuffer()
     };
    yield return www.SendWebRequest();
```

Comment: я не знаю. что это за штука такаая `UnityWebRequest`, но у неё по идее должен быть тайиаут

Comment: @tym32167 да, вы правы, там такое есть, но только если таймаут выйдет то будет ошибка, а закинуть данную строку в блок try-catch нельзя

Comment: Включая yield  нельзя, но вроде, в catch можно, если я не ошибаюсь вернуть какой-нибудь null.

Comment: разве отсутсвие интернета не есть ошибка? По моему все логично

Comment: @tym32167 конечно, но отловить эту ошибку нужно

Comment: ну отловите. `Response ret = null; try{ret=www.requrest()}catch{ret=null}; yield return ret;` ?

Comment: @tym32167 ошибка именно при отправлении запроса

Comment: именно отправку запроса я вам обернул в try-catch

Comment: @tym32167 да не, нельзя в юнити вставлять yield return в try который имеет catch, а только finally, но я решил проблему, я не так понял суть работы finally, я думал он вызываеться как catch только в независимости от того какой тип исключения вызвал его, а тут оказываеться всегда, вот у меня и была проблема

Comment: `нельзя в юнити вставлять yield return в try который имеет catch` я и не вставлял, пересмотрите мой код

Comment: @tym32167 да, но ошибка бы далее была, она же именно в самой отправке запроса yield return

Comment: отправка запроса внутри try-catch - `try{ret=www.requrest()}catch{ret=null};`, там, где `yield return ret;` никакого запроса нет